# Stacked Scrolling in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I achieve the below stacked scrolling effect in Android Jetpack Compose?

[image: Sample]

(Taken from [here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/37148547/Swift-UI-Libraries-and-Java-Components-iOS-Android/modules/364210287))

Any pointers on the best components to use for this type of functionality?